# What should i do with this tree?

Tags: trees, pruning

Some branches are not producing leaves. And it it branching out. What should I do with the tree. Prune or..?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need a close up photo of the leaves to decide what the tree is, but what you see at the top is die back. That occurs for a reason, so check the entire trunk to make sure it is completely healthy, with no evidence of fungal growths, soggy or weeping areas , etc.

Comment: I'd also suggest a close-up of the trunk. I think I may know what the problem could be, but as Bamboo noted, we need to ID the tree first.

Comment: What kind of tree ? What location ? Do the leaves show any problem? Recent history of rain / water ?

Comment: Thanks all. Added image of leaves. Trunk has some holes, so we’re assuming a bug. We’re in Colorado... some folks around here say to take the tree down, some say to try the dead branches. Nobody knows for sure. Would hate to cut it down...

Answer (score 1):

Probably a Siberian or Chinese Elm, depending on whether it makes seed in spring or fall. Not long lived trees , and I think, tend to have sections die like yours. ( I had one in IL ). You can prune out bad areas but I suggest looking in your neighborhood for types of  trees you might replace it with. For CO , I would look at blue spruce , common but good ; mountain ash , not big but fairly fast and interesting.